# Synology DS1813+ RAID 5 with iSCSI IO wait perfomance issue

Tags: performance, vmware-esxi, iscsi, raid5, synology

I'm have RAID 5 on Synology DS1813+ (DSM Version: DSM 5.0-4493 Update 4) with 8 ST4000DM000-1F2168 disk, usind as NAS and iSCSI/NFS targer for ESXi.

In low read/write rate from disk have more io wait, please have you any ideas?

```
SRV1> uname -a
Linux SRV1 3.2.40 #4493 SMP Thu Aug 21 21:46:06 CST 2014 x86_64 GNU/Linux synology_cedarview_1813+
```

**nmon** output

```
DiskName Busy  Read WriteKB
sda       63%    0.0    0.0
sda1       0%    0.0    0.0
sda2      28%  115.7    0.0
sda3      50%    0.0    0.0
sdb       50%    0.0    0.0
sdb1       0%    0.0    0.0
sdb2      20%   85.8    0.0
sdb3      37%    0.0    0.0
<skip omitted>
Totals Read-MB/s=0.7      Writes-MB/s=0.0      Transfers/sec=884.8
```

**CPU** output

```
CPU  User%  Sys% Wait% Idle
  1   0.5   2.5  76.9  20.1
  2   0.0   1.0  59.1  39.9
  3   0.0  19.1  18.1  62.8
  4   0.0   2.5  18.5  79.0
```

**RAID** info:

```
SRV1> mdadm --detail /dev/md2
/dev/md2:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Mon Jan 20 12:26:15 2014
     Raid Level : raid5
     Array Size : 27316073792 (26050.64 GiB 27971.66 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3902296256 (3721.52 GiB 3995.95 GB)
   Raid Devices : 8
  Total Devices : 8
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Mon Jan 18 08:51:10 2016
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 8
Working Devices : 8
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

           Name : SRV1:2  (local to host SRV1)
           UUID : 690db49f:cc6aebea:e4dc7a24:b8c4a142
         Events : 66

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        3        0      active sync   /dev/hda3
       1       8       19        1      active sync   /dev/hdb3
       2       8       35        2      active sync   /dev/hdc3
       3       8       51        3      active sync   /dev/sdd3
       4       8       67        4      active sync   /dev/hde3
       5       8       83        5      active sync   /dev/sdf3
       6       8       99        6      active sync   /dev/sdg3
       7       8      115        7      active sync   /dev/sdh3
```

In dmesg:

```
[23334402.188177] __fd_async_epio_request_handle: 6 callbacks suppressed
[23334402.194671] iSCSI: iSCSI: EPIO[/volume1/@iSCSITrg/iSCSI_3_Extent_LUN-L1_000], opcode[89], error(-65539), pos(10578606080)
[23334402.194937] iSCSI: iSCSI: EPIO[/volume1/@iSCSITrg/iSCSI_3_Extent_LUN-L1_000], opcode[89], error(-65539), pos(10578606080)
```

Comment: I am not familiar with the Synology DS1813. Is `SRV1> mdadm --detail /dev/md2` from the unit's command line interface? It seems to be using software raid.

Comment: Yep, it's software raid with 2x SiI 3132 controller.

Comment: I am not sure if you can run these, or if it will affect the support/warranty, but what the the output of:

`blockdev --getra /dev/md0` and `cat  /sys/block/md0/md/stripe_cache_size`

Comment: @Gmck: > blockdev --getra /dev/md0
8192

> cat /sys/block/md0/md/stripe_cache_size
cat: can't open '/sys/block/md0/md/stripe_cache_size': No such file or directory

Comment: You could try increasing the cache and see if that helps. If you can do this in the unit's admin interface, that is probably better. But if you want to try from the command line `blockdev --setra 20480 /dev/md0`

If that does not help, contact the vendor and get them to troubleshoot further.

Comment: @Gmck Thx for reply, this no help(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34599/discussion-between-t3mp-and-gmck).